# Meta box dropdown of custom posts

Tags: wp-query, metabox

I am trying to display a dropdown select metabox on the "add new" page of a custom post type which displays a drop down list of titles from a separate custom post type ( it's an effort to relate the two CPT's together - one being "clients" and the other being "projects" so that when creating a new project one would be required to select a client from the drop down select ).

All works well except for the fact that somehow the query is affecting WordPress because when i click "add new **project**" instead of an empty field for the title like you'd normally get it is populated instead with the title of the first **CLIENT**. I thought that by adding wp_reset_postdata() that it would solve the problem but it didn't. Can anyone help? ( I am only adding what i think is the relevant/problematic piece of code as the metabox code itself works as expected as far as i can see and i assume the problem is with the way i've done the query)

```
  <select name="my_meta_box_select" id="my_meta_box_select">
  <?php 
  $my_loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'clients', 'posts_per_page' => 10 ) );
  while ( $my_loop->have_posts() ) : $my_loop->the_post();
  $title = get_the_title();
  ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $title ?>" <?php selected( $selected, $title ); ?>><?php echo $title ?></option>
  <?php
  endwhile;
  ?>            
  </select>

  <?php
  wp_reset_postdata();
  }
```

Comment: You may be interesteed in the Posts-2-Posts plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/posts-to-posts/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is just create a custom taxonomy type to share between both custom post types that are dynamically created when a new post of the Clients type is created with the same title, then you can associate them without any custom meta handling.

Comment: i was going for custom meta over taxonomy because i thought that in general for unique values you'd use custom meta - so for example a project can have one and only one value for client. It seems like this custom meta vs taxonomy issue comes up all the time - i thought i had it sorted with that view - am i wrong

Comment: Yea, while that is true that you would use custom meta for new data, with what you're describing doing could easily be done programmatically to where it would be a better option than custom meta, in my personal opinion.

Answer (score 2):

i think you need to replace

wp_reset_postdata();

with

wp_reset_query();

at least that works for me in a quick front-end test

Comment: WP_Query doesn't affect the $wp_query global, so you _shouldn't_ need to reset the query.

Comment: only just got to try this - it didnt have any effect. thanks though

Comment: sucks, don't know what is so different about the backend. my other suggestion would be to use get_posts() which i have definitely used before to create drop downs in metaboxes. http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Reset_after_Postlists_with_offset